# copy multi-dimension C array to Matlab mxArray type

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm writing a c++ code that opens Matlab API engine. In the demo file Matlab_ROOT/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp, it shows how to copy a simple 1d c style array to a mxArray:

```
mxArray *T = NULL; double time[10] = {};
T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 1,10,mxREAL);
memcpy((void*)mxGetPr(T), (void*)time, sizeof(time));
```

I can understand this code; so a 1d `mxArray` object stores the elements linearly.

However, suppose I have a 2d (or more) c array and `mxArray` of same size:

```
double time[3][5]; 
mxArray *T; 
T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,5,mxREAL);
```

and I want to copy the elements of the c array time into `mxArray` `T`. How can I do this? I suppose if I use `memcpy`, it would depend on the sequence of element storage in `mxArray` objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what the dimensionality of your `mxArray` matlab always stores it as a continuous chunk in memory (column first order). That is, if your matrix `M` is 2-by-3

```
M = [ 11, 12, 13;
      21, 22, 23 ];
```

In memory, Matlab stores it as

```
[11, 21, 12, 22, 13, 23]
```

(The same order you'll get if you do `M(:)`).

Therefore, to convert a `double[3][5]` to `mxArray` you'll have to issue *several* `memcpy` commands:

```
double* ptr = mxGetPr( T );
for ( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    memcpy( (void*)(ptr+i*5), (void*)time[i], 5*sizeof(double) );
```

Comment: Thanks I just realise Matlab and c stores 2d array in different order, and these are termed as 'column major' and 'row major'. I can also only issue one memcpy command to throw the c array into mxArray as it is, and do a transpose on the Matlab array later.

Comment: but the initialisation would be mxCreateDoubleMatrix(5,3,mxREAL) instead of putting (3,5)

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is illustrated in another Matlab demo file matlabroot/extern/examples/refbook/arrayFillSetData.c. Things works well except that the c style array has to be in a Matlab-supported type and in linear form. Matlab stores 2d array in column major and c in row major, so care must be taken. A transpose action might be needed.

```
#define ROWS 2
#define COLUMNS 2
#define ELEMENTS 4

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
UINT16_T *dynamicData;                        /* pointer to dynamic data */
const UINT16_T data[] = {2, 3, 2, 1};  /* existing data */
mwSize index;

/* Check for proper number of arguments. */
if ( nrhs != 0 ) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:arrayFillSetData:rhs",
            "This function takes no input arguments.");
} 

/* Create a local array and load data */
dynamicData = mxCalloc(ELEMENTS, sizeof(UINT16_T));
for ( index = 0; index < ELEMENTS; index++ ) {
    dynamicData[index] = data[index];
}

/* Create a 0-by-0 mxArray; you will allocate the memory dynamically */
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxUINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);

/* Point mxArray to dynamicData */
mxSetData(plhs[0], dynamicData);
mxSetM(plhs[0], ROWS);
mxSetN(plhs[0], COLUMNS);

/* Do not call mxFree(dynamicData) because plhs[0] points to dynamicData */

return;
}
```